# Incorrect icon order when a question is closed for multiple reasons

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, close-reasons

[image]

When a question is closed for multiple reasons, the close reasons are displayed below the "closed by" line. However, the light bulb icon is still shown above the eye icon.

Either the icon order should be swapped or the close reasons should be moved back above the list of close voters.

This could be related to both close reasons being community-specific. Not sure.